# Why is using an Applescript library preventing me from running a shell script?

Tags: applescript

So I'm working on a project where I need multiple functions from the text library from [the AppleScript stdlib](https://github.com/mattneub/applescript-stdlib).
So I do something like this:

```applescript
use script "text"

-- Do some stuff with text

do shell script "echo hello"
```

Compiling this, however, produces an error about how an end of line was expected.

Searching through the terminology for do, shell and script produces no result.

Is there either a way to stop using a script after some time without wrapping the entire thing inside a tell statement or to prevent this behavior altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: Question

> Compiling this, however, produces an error about how an end of line was expected.

Add `use scripting additions` after: `use script "text"`

From: [use (scripting additions)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-SW5)

> Scripting addition commands are handled differently if a script has use commands. If a script has one or more use commands of any kind, scripting addition commands are not available by default. You must explicitly indicate that you wish to use scripting additions, either with a use or using terms from command

From: Question

> Is there either a way to stop using a script

You can use it as `using terms from script "text"` ... `end using terms from`

Have a look at: [using terms from](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-SW1)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>   using terms from ( application  |  script  | scripting additions) 
>       [ statement ]... 
>   end [ using terms from ]
> ```